# How to get all classes used in decorator design pattern?

Tags: java, decorator

So I'm implementing decorator design patter in java.

Overall I have this call which works correctly.

```
CrewMember crewMember = new Captain(new ChiefEngineer(new CrewMemberImpl()));
```

Now I have a question, how could I call a method as a `crewMember` from `ChiefEngineer` for example(which is not in the base interface).

What I would want ideally:

```
crewMember.methodFromChiefEngineerClass();
```

Maybe there is a way to get all related classed from crewMember? Using instanceof somehow? Or am I getting it wrong

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a proxy-method in `Captain` which calls the corresponding method of the contained `ChiefEngineer` object.

```
public class Captain {
    private final ChiefEngineer chiefEngineer;

    public Captain(final ChiefEngineer chiefEngineer) {
        this.chiefEngineer = chiefEngineer;
    }

    public void methodFromChiefEngineerClass() {
        chiefEngineer.methodFromChiefEngineerClass();
    }

}
```

Comment: But that would be wrong from decorator design patter prospective, wouldn't it? Because if I have like a 100 decorators, you suggest I would need to create for each one of them a corresponding method?

Comment: I would need more universal solution, as I would want to call Captains, ChiefEngineers etc. methods if I add them as a decorator.

Comment: Also I can create such object  `CrewMember crewMember = new ChiefEngineer(new Captain(new CrewMemberImpl()));` I swaped Captain and ChiefEngineer and still would need all of the methods provided by both classes.

Comment: @developer1, the "Decorator" pattern is actually about having a base interface, which the decorator should extend. One could also create a "decorator base class" which just proxies all methods, and then only override the methods which a specific decorator should alter.

Comment: @developer1, why is a base interface not an option? 
And what exactly should the decorator do - is it just a "marker" or should it change the original method's behaviour?

Comment: I'm not sure if understand it correctly. But from my perspective I could have a Captain, a Captain-ChiefEngineer, a Cook-Captain etc. And all of these object should be able to call specific to their roles methods. For example if every crew member can work(), and only Cook can work() and cook(), by having Cook-Captain I could cook(), work() and etc.

Comment: So Captain-Cook would change the functionality of work() which is in base interface CrewMember and also add two new methods cook() and steer(). So that if I make a new creMember with Cook and Captain decorators, I could use all of their methods.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in the `Captain` class to get the `ChiefEngineer` object and use that to call methods inside the `ChiefEngineer` class.

```
public class Captain {

  private final ChiefEngineer engineer;

  public Captain(final ChiefEngineer engineer) {
    this.engineer = engineer;
  } 

  public ChiefEngineer getChiefEngineer() {
    return this.engineer;
  }
}
```

Then do

```
crewMember.getChiefEngineer().methodFromChiefEngineerClass();
```

Comment: This would violate the Law of Demeter. Also, it would imply the Captain and the ChiefEngineer are two different people, which does not fit the Decorator design pattern.